# Get values from an emitted tuple with a nimbus client

Tags: java, apache-storm, nimbus

I have a running topology... on a remote cluster ... runs like a charm...

```java
StormTopology runningTopology= new StormTopology();
nimbus.getClient().send_getTopology("MyNewTopo-14-1451353801");
runningTopology = nimbus.getClient().recv_getTopology();
Bolt readerBolt = new Bolt();

readerBolt = runningTopology.get_bolts().get("determineClickType");    
System.out.println("Bolt com : " + readerBolt.get_bolt_object().toString());

/* Console dump: */
/* Returns: <ComponentObject serialized_java:80 01 80 01 00 02 00 00 00 ....... */ 

/* More Console dump: 
Stream : StreamInfo(output_fields:[id, ack-val], direct:false)
Stream : StreamInfo(output_fields:[clickedType, count], direct:false)
Stream : StreamInfo(output_fields:[id], direct:false)
Stream : StreamInfo(output_fields:[task-info, data-points], direct:false)
Stream : StreamInfo(output_fields:[event], direct:false)
*/
```

I don't know how to proceed, to read the actual information which is emitted from  a `BaseBasicBolt` defined as `"determineClickType"`

What is the correct approach to *get values from an emitted tuple by a bolt with a nimbus client*?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get the tuples, that are emitted by a bolt? If you want to do this, you need to define a second bolt and connect it to the first bolt:

```java
TopologyBuilder b = new TopologyBuilder();
b.addSpout(...);
b.addBolt("determineClickType", new MyBolt());
b.addBolt("receiver", new MyReceiverBolt()).shuffleGrouping("determineClickType");
```

The bolt with name "receiver" will now get the output tuples from the bolt called "determineClickType".

Comment: thanks, the thing is, I dont want to rebalance or add it to a running topology. The reason for this, I want to write a reporting client. 

I hoped the thrift client was able to return the data passing through, spouts and/or bolts... so its more a thrift 'metadata only' client...
Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Storm has no built-in support to give data to an external client. You need to code this in your Bolt.execute() manullay... (for example via opening a network connection the external client can connect to)

Comment: Indeed, think of using:
1 - Statsd and metricsConsumer ...
2 - data logger ... 
3 - ... suggestions ...  ???

Comment: I guess it highly depends on your use case and expected output data rates you want to process in your client... Maybe it would even make sense to use Kafka as an buffer between Storm and your client.